# Decode a base64 data to image

Tags: uiimage, base64, swift3, nsdata, xcode8

This code doesn't working with Swift 3 anymore.

```
imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: mediaFile, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
```

So is this one.

```
imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: mediaFile, options: .allZeros)
```

Comment: Swift 3 you are supposed to use Data instead of NSData.

Comment: `if let imageData =  Data(base64Encoded: base64EncodedImageString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters),
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
    print(image.size)
}
`

Comment: mediaFile is a String consisting of base64 encoded characters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36831069/2303865

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of using `NSData` use directly Swift 3 native `Data`.

```
if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: mediaFile, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
    let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)
}
```

Comment: What is the media file? String Or Data

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 4.1**:

Sometimes string has prefix `data:image/png;base64` will make `base64Encoded` return `nil`, for this situation:

```swift
extension String {
    func base64ToImage() -> UIImage? {
        if let url = URL(string: self),let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

Demo code:

```swift
let results = text.matches(for: "data:image\\/([a-zA-Z]*);base64,([^\\\"]*)")
for imageString in results {
    autoreleasepool {
        let image = imageString.base64ToImage()
    }
}

extension String {
    func matches(for regex: String) -> [String] {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
            let results = regex.matches(in: self, range:  NSRange(self.startIndex..., in: self))
            return results.map {
                //self.substring(with: Range($0.range, in: self)!)
                String(self[Range($0.range, in: self)!])
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

PS: For more about data uri:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

https://github.com/nodes-vapor/data-uri

Comment: Nice answer! Can you please update the code for latest swift? Getting following warnings:  'substring(with:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript. And  "Unused result." both for this: `self.substring(with: Range($0.range, in: self)!)`

Answer (score 4):

**Swift**

Swift 3.0 does not recommend to use NS any more and the same case with `NSData` as well

```
 if let decodedImageData = Data(base64Encoded: mediaFile, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
        let image = UIImage(data: decodedImageData)
    }
```

**In Objective-C**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:base64String];    
NSData *decodedImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:decodedImageData];
```

Answer (score 3):

I implemented this as UIImage extension

```
extension UIImage {

    /* 
     @brief decode image base64
     */
    static func decodeBase64(toImage strEncodeData: String!) -> UIImage {

        if let decData = Data(base64Encoded: strEncodeData, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters), strEncodeData.characters.count > 0 {
            return UIImage(data: decData)!
        }
        return UIImage()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this way

```
let data = NSData(base64Encoded: mediaFile, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

Hope it will help you