# Base64 encode decode for image URL in Swift 3

Tags: base64, swift3, xcode8

This is how  I encoded:

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string : pictURL)!
let imageData : NSData = NSData.init(contentsOf: url as URL)!
let str64 = imageData.base64EncodedData(options: .lineLength64Characters)
// next line my code to save in core data just ignore it
```

The value for `encoded data = 3286 bytes`. I think it is wrong

```
let pictEncoded = person.value(forKeyPath: "pictureurl") as! String

if let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: pictEncoded, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters),
       let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    {
        cell.imgView.image = image
    }
```

Comment: `cell.imgView.image = UIImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: pictEncoded, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode base64\_encode Image from JSON in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831069/decode-base64-encode-image-from-json-in-swift)

Comment: @LeoDabus: Value of optional type 'Data?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? .......

i tried to fix it but it crashes

Comment: You need to show how you are encoding it

Comment: Are you sure that pictureurl is an encoded image string and not an URL absolute string?

Comment: @LeoDabus question edited...

Comment: you have to drop the NS prefix from NSURL and NSData

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode a base64 data to image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967293/decode-a-base64-data-to-image)

Comment: guys! i edited my question

Comment: i think im wrong about how i encoded my image data... what's the proper way in swift 3 of encoding url image source?