# Cannot convert value of type 'NSData?' to type 'Data' in coercion

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, base64

Im trying to convert a base64 string to an UIImage

First. I decode the String as shown below

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: decodeIMG, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

Then I try to convert the decoded data to an UIImage like this:

```
let decodedIamge = UIImage(data: decodedData as Data)
```

But on that line I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSData?' to type 'Data' in coercion

I already tried using another approach to convert it by using an extension that looks like this

```
extension String {
//: ### Base64 encoding a string
    func base64Encoded() -> String? {
        if let data = self.data(using: .utf8) {
            return data.base64EncodedString()
        }
        return nil
    }

//: ### Base64 decoding a string
    func base64Decoded() -> String? {
        if let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) {
            return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And get this error

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'base64Encoded:', expected
>   'map:')

Comment: Why are you using `NSData` at all? Just use `Data`.

Comment: It used to work like that, But then I updated Xcode and got this problem 

So instead of: 
let decodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: decodeIMG, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

I should do: 
let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: decodeIMG)

Thanks for your reply

Comment: String conversion to data using utf8 encoding will never return nil. `return Data(utf8).base64EncodedString()`

Comment: @LeoDabus the error in the extension comes from the decoding part :  Data(base64Encoded: self) - ERROR: Incorrect argument label in call (have 'base64Encoded:', expected 'map:')
Thanks anyways

Comment: @JesusRojas try with different Data.Base64DecodingOptions

Comment: @JesusRojas if you code doesn't compile try cleaning your project. Have you tryed that in a new playground file?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/36831114/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus I still get Incorrect argument label in call (have 'base64Encoded:', expected 'map:') when I try to use Data(base64Encoded: self) after cleaning

Comment: @JesusRojas What is your Swift / Xcode version?

Comment: @LeoDabus Xcode 10.1 Swift 4.2

Comment: Have you tried that code in a new playground file? try `extension String {
    func base64Encoded() -> String {
        return Data(utf8).base64EncodedString()
    }

    func base64Decoded() -> String? {
        if let data = Data(base64Encoded: self, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
            return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        return nil
    }
}`

Comment: Make sure you don't have a custom `class` or `structure` called `Data` in your project

Comment: @LeoDabus It was the structure thing but the Structure was on another file lol
Thank you so much <3